How to make products in Commerce catalog clickable?
I'm making an eCommerce website using Drupal Core 10 and Commerce.
I've set up pretty much everything without problems and I got my test products to show up in the "Products" page, but they're not clickable... now what does it mean, you may ask, well, hovering the cursor on the product's image or its title won't turn it into a hand and it's not clickable, so it's impossible to open up the product's page with all of its details.
I've also got few other problems along, but I wanna try to fix one thing at a time.
Hovering the product's picture, the cursor remains the same as it's not a clickable link:

Hovering the product's title, turns the cursor into a "I" cursor, indicating that it's a normal text and not a link:

Here's a screenshot of how I set up the products page's view:


This is a basic Views issue, not specific to Commerce Core. Those fields on your View have options that must be enabled to add the links. For the title field, it's "Link to the Product", and for the image field, it's a select list that lets you link to "Content".
